# shell script: count lines and sum numbers from multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to count the number of lines in a *.CSV* file, and sum the last numeric column.  I need to make this for a `crontab`, so, it has to be a script.

This code counts the number of lines:

```
egrep -i String file_name_201611* | \
egrep -i "cdr,20161115" | \
awk -F"," '{print $4}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

This code sums the last column:

```
egrep -i String file_name_201611* | \
egrep -i ".cdr,20161115"| \
awk -F"," '{print $8}' | paste -s -d"+" | bc
```

Lines looks like:

```
COMGPRS,CGSCO05,COMGPRS_CGSCO05_400594.dat,processed_cdr_20161117100941_00627727.cdr,20161117095940,20161117,18,46521
```

The expected output:

```
CGSCO05,sum_#_lines, Sum_$8
CGSCO05, 225, 1500
```

Comment: This can be entirely done using `awk`, without too many pipes. How does the input file look like. Add it to the question along with required output so that it would be useful for people looking at it.

Comment: You can provide a sample input file and an expected output along with it!

Comment: yeah, you're right, here is how the line looks like:   COMGPRS,CGGCO02,COMGPRS_CGGCO02_689072.dat,processed_cdr_20161109131123_01409950.cdr,20161109130111,20161109,225,48416

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    k=0;
    FS=","
}
{
    if ($2 in counter){
        counter[$2] = counter[$2] + 1;
        sum_8[$2] = sum_8[$2] + $8;
    }else{
        k = k + 1;
        counter[$2] = 1;
        sum_8[$2] =  $8;
        name[k] = $2;
    }

}
END{
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
        printf "%s, %i, %i\n", name[k], counter[name[k]], sum_8[name[k]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Riccardo Petraglia, it gives me a clearer idea, although the result is a bit different, I was trying to do something like this: `code` #!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=",";
}
{
        if (($1 == "COMGPRS") && ($2 == "ALK_01P")) {
                if (substr($5,1,8) == "20161115") {
                    sum+=$8;
                }
        }
}
END {
                print "Registros," $2 "," $sum;
}

Comment: I answered your question.. ;)

Comment: I have a directoy with files .CSV with names like this : 'ESTCOL_GPRS_201611*', the contents of these files are strings like these:
'COMGPRS,CGHW12,COMGPRS_CGHW12_610617.dat,processed_cdr_20161117061743_01680861.cdr,20161117060116,20161117,225,42832'

I wanna to count the unique occurrences for the column 2 and sum it, after sum all values column 8. output like this:
'Files      Records '
'2,433 , 119,930,636'

Comment: what could be missing is a `cat ESTCOL_GPRS_201611*` that join all the files together... So, if the scipt is saved in a file called `script.awk`, you should execute `cat ESTCOL_GPRS_201611* | awk -f script.awk`. If this does not work, explain why or it would be nice to mark the answer are correct...

Answer (score 0):

`sort` a *CSV* file by field #2, keeping only lines with unique entries, then print the number of unique lines, and the `sum` of column #8 from those unique lines:

```
sort -t, -k2 -u foo.csv | datamash -t, count 2  sum 8
```